# Insert on CommitEditingStyle Monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

Basically what I would like is if the edit button is clicked, a "Create" cell is appended to my list which would navigate to a separate screen controller to add.  I currently have the delete working as well as the insert (where it just inserts a blank cell into your table).  Can anyone help with this?  Thanks.  THe following is my code...

```
private class UserAlertsTableViewSource : UITableViewSource

    {

        const string DEFAULT_CELL = "UserAlertsCell";

        private UserAlertsListController _useralertslistController;

        public UserAlertsTableViewSource( UserAlertsListController useralertslistController)
        {
            this._useralertslistController = useralertslistController;  
        }



        public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, int section)
        {
            return _useralertslistController.Alerts.Count;

        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            int row = indexPath.Row;

            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(DEFAULT_CELL) as UserAlertsCell;   


            if (null == cell) {
                cell = new UserAlertsCell();
                var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("UserAlertsCell", cell, null);
                cell = Runtime.GetNSObject(views.ValueAt(0)) as UserAlertsCell;


            }




            cell.Name = _useralertslistController.Alerts[indexPath.Row].LakeName;
                cell.AlertLevel = _useralertslistController.Alerts[indexPath.Row].AlertLevel;
            cell.AlertVariance = _useralertslistController.Alerts[indexPath.Row].AlertVariance;





            return cell;
        }


        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            SelectItem (tableView, indexPath);
        }

        public override void AccessoryButtonTapped(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            SelectItem(tableView, indexPath);
        }

        public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return 60f;

        }

        public void SelectItem(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
        //  MapController mapController = new MapController();
        //  _lakelevelsController.NavigationController.PushViewController(mapController, true);
        }


    //  public override bool CanEditRow (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    //  {
    //      return true;
    //  }



    public override UITableViewCellEditingStyle EditingStyleForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {

            var count = this._useralertslistController.Alerts.Count;
            if (indexPath.Row == count-1 )
            {
                return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Insert;
            }else
            {
                return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete;
            }





        }




        public override void CommitEditingStyle (UITableView tableView, UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {

        switch (editingStyle)
            {
            case UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete:

            this._useralertslistController.Alerts.RemoveAt (indexPath.Row);
            tableView.DeleteRows (new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath } , UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
                break;


            case UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Insert:
            this._useralertslistController.Alerts.Insert ( indexPath.Row, new AlertSettings ());
                tableView.InsertRows (new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade); 

                break;

            case UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None:
                Console.WriteLine ("CommitEditingStyle: None called");
                break;

        }
        }

        public override void MoveRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath sourceIndexPath, NSIndexPath destinationIndexPath)
        {

            var item = this._useralertslistController.Alerts[sourceIndexPath.Row];
            int deleteAt = sourceIndexPath.Row;
            if (destinationIndexPath.Row < sourceIndexPath.Row)
            {
                deleteAt = sourceIndexPath.Row + 1;
            }
            this._useralertslistController.Alerts.Insert (destinationIndexPath.Row, item);
            this._useralertslistController.Alerts.RemoveAt (deleteAt);



        }



    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  What is it doing (or not doing)?

Comment: Why not just always display the "Create" cell instead of tying it into the edit button?

Comment: Thanks Jason was just thinking about that.. how would I turn that cell into a navigation(dialog) cell while leaving all the other cells the same?

Answer (score 0):

In your GetCell() and RowSelected() methods just add case for when it is the "Create" cell.

```
if (indexPath.Row == _useralertscontroller.Alerts.Count)
{
  // this is the +1 cell, so do something special
}
```

You will also need to modify RowsInSection() to add an extra row.